# Sending JSON with Flask and parse with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm trying to return a JSON with Flask and send it to an html and then parse it with JS.
However, my string is getting modified and this throws an error.

My JSON string looks like this:

```
json_to_parse = {"input":"noecall","output":"onecall","count":1},{"input":"oncall","output":"onecall","count":1}
```

output:

```
var b = '{&#34;input&#34;:&#34;noecall&#34;,&#34;output&#34;:&#34;onecall&#34;,&#34;count&#34;:1},{&#34;input&#34;:&#34;oncall&#34;,&#34;output&#34;:&#34;onecall&#34;,&#34;count&#34;:1}';
```

It seems to convert the " into &#34 and it does the same with ', however this causes a lot of problems.

My Flask return code is:

```
return render_template("parse_json.html", json_to_parse = json_to_parse)
```

I have tried to do this with the string:

```
r = json.dumps(json_to_parse)
loaded_r = json.loads(r)
```

in parse.json.html this is how I get the string:

```
var b = '{{ json_to_parse}}';
```

Also tried to remove and add [] around the string, same results.

Any fix would be greatly appreciated, tried to google and solve this with many creative ways for a while now. But obviously without any luck.

Comment: your `json_to_parse` is not valid json, neither javascript. I think you want an array ? `[{}, {}]`

Comment: @UlysseBN, I agree that `json_to_parse` is not syntactically valid json or javascript. But it _is_ syntactically valid Python. Perhaps when they say "My JSON string looks like this", they mean "the Python object which I will eventually convert into JSON looks like this"

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear from the code you supply, but I *think* the problem is that Jinja escapes your JSON. In your `parse_json.html`, you have to specify that your data is "safe":

```
var b = '{{ json_to_parse|safe }}';
```

For more information, see the docs on HTML escaping: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#html-escaping and the `safe` filter: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#safe